# Difference between Texture2D and Texture2DMS in DirectX11

Tags: directx, textures, directx-11, texture2d, depth-buffer

I'm using SharpDX and I want to do antialiasing in the Depth buffer. I need to store the Depth Buffer as a texture to use it later. So is it a good idea if this texture is a Texture2DMS? Or should I take another approach?

What I really want to achieve is:

1) Depth buffer scaling

2) Depth test supersampling

(terms I found in section 3.2 of this paper: http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Cole_2010_TFM/cole_tfm_preprint.pdf

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in points 1 and 2?  What do you mean by "scaling"?  Regarding super-sampling, MSAA by its nature always super-samples depth.

Comment: It's hard for me to clarify that because I saw that in a paper and I don't exactly know what that means, and I thought maybe it was a common term. I found it here at the end of section 3.2 (Visibility testing): http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Cole_2010_TFM/cole_tfm_preprint.pdf

Comment: Are you trying to implement the line rendering technique described in the paper?  If so, please clarify this in your question text.  If not, what rendering technique are you trying to implement that requires a higher-than-normal-resolution depth buffer?

Comment: Yes I am! But I think that's a big task for a question. Does it really add to the question?

Comment: It does help, since "is this a good approach" requires context of the end goal, and the specifics (1 and 2) are too vague to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper calls for a depth pre-pass.  Since this pass requires no color, you should leave the render target unbound, and use an "empty" pixel shader.  For depth, you should create a Texture2D (not MS) at 2x or 4x (or some other 2Nx) the width and height of the final render target that you're going to use.  This isn't really "supersampling" (since the pre-pass is an independent phase with no actual pixel output) but it's similar.

For the second phase, the paper calls for doing multiple samples of the high-resolution depth buffer from the pre-pass.  If you followed the sizing above, every pixel will correspond to some (2N)^2 depth values.  You'll need to read these values and average them.  Fortunately, there's a hardware-accelerated way to do this (called PCF) using [SampleCmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509696%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a [COMPARISON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sampler type.  This samples a 2x2 stamp, compares each value to a specified value (pass in the second-phase calculated depth here, and don't forget to add some epsilon value (e.g. 1e-5)), and returns the averaged result.  Do 2x2 stamps to cover the entire area of the first-phase depth buffer associated with this pixel, and average the results.  The final result represents how much of the current line's spine corresponds to the foremost depth of the pre-pass.  Because of the PCF's smooth filtering behavior, as lines become visible, they will slowly fade in, as opposed to the aliased "dotted" line effect described in the paper.

Comment: I'm a bit lost about how to render to a texture and put the depth information there. Can you maybe point me to a resource tutorial that can help me? I've seen this one: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut22.html ... seems quite good but it is rendering the normal scene and not the depth.

Comment: @c4sh It's not so much that you're rendering depth to a texture.  Rather, you're doing a standard rendering pass with _only_ the depth view bound.  This causes depth to be written as normal, with no overhead for rendering color.  It's the same as rendering the normal scene once, and just not using the resulting render target data, but with better performance.